# Generating random numbers and a sequence key in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, key, generator, sequence

So, here's the deal. I have an m*n size bitmap image that i intend to perform LSB image steganography on. I don't want to store the secret information in the image pixels on a round-robin fashion (first piece of secret information stored in the first pixel, second piece of information stored in the second pixel, ...etc). What i want to do is to generate a random sequence that would represent the locations of the pixels so that the secret information is harder to detect eg:(first piece of secret information stored in the 543rd pixel, second piece of information stored in the 27th pixel, third piece of information stored in the 221st pixel, ...etc). Also i want to be able to generate sort of a special key or seed number for that sequence so that i could regenerate the same random sequence at the receiving end and get the secret information in order (get first piece of secret information stored in the 543rd pixel, get second piece of information stored in the 27th pixel, get third piece of information stored in the 221st pixel, ...etc). So that the secret information is very hard to extract without that key.
I'm doing this for a college project, i would really appreciate the help guys :).

Comment: Cool question, give me a second to try something.

Comment: @Ahmed After I got the code ready you just deleted the question on shuffling images. Anyway, sorry for tracking you here. [Have a look!](http://pastebin.com/ubZF8sJJ) I have played around with it for a while lol.

Comment: @Ray yeah i realized it wasn't worth answering as the code was full of mistakes other than the ones you've mentioned, and after i managed to correct all of them the computation delay wasn't that bad. I also wrote another function to reverse the operation and convert the random noise-like image generated with shuffle() back into it's original form and now everything is working just fine. But i'll make use of what you've written in your version, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo:

```
m = 256; % height of image
n = 256; % width of image
seed_key = 123456; % secret key
img = zeros(m, n, 'uint8'); % sample greyscale image (all black)
rng(seed_key); % seed the random number generator
idxs1 = randperm(m*n); % generate a set of *linear* indices into the image
rng(seed_key); % seed the random number generator again (as a test)
idxs2 = randperm(m*n); % generate another set of *linear* indices (should match first)
all(idxs1 == idxs2) % prove that indices match
```

Comment: You rock! I might need your help again sometime soon, is there someway that i can tag you in a question?

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't think there's any way to tag me -- just have to hope I see your next question I guess :).